# glsl minus in swizzling

Tags: opengl, glsl, swizzling

Can swizzling in GLSL somehow be with minus? For example: vec.-yx-wz  
The purpose for this is to get 2d normale with simple define:

```
#DEFINE NORMALE_PACK(v) (v).-yx-wz
#DEFINE NORMALE_1(v) dir.-yx
#DEFINE NORMALE_2(v) vec.-wz

void main(){
... 
float l = dot( NORMALE_PACK(dir), dir2);
}
```

without this I achive this with:

```
void main(){
... 
vec4 normale = vec4(-dir.y, dir.x, -dir.w, dir.z);      // +1 cycle on modern hardware, more - on older
float l = dot( normale, dir2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 cycle compared to what? Do you have other option working that is only one instruction and no additional overhead?

No shader assembly language i've seen can perform per-component negation. What you described is two swizzled `mov`s (one of which is with negation prefix), like

```
MOV result.position.xz, -vertex.position.yyww;
MOV result.position.yw, vertex.position.xxzz;
```

You can reduce it to one instruction by using something like `vec4 n = vec4(dir.yxwz) * vec4(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0)`. That would be like:

```
PARAM c[1] = { { -1, 1 } };
MUL result.position, vertex.position.yxwz, c[0].xyxy;
```

(in both cases i've used `result.position` and `vertex.position` from ARB vertex program just as example).

*But*, it uses extra constant register, so it is not necessarily better.

Of course, both versions could be wrapped into macro.

*update*

I now see what you wanted to do. Something that generates code like (for latest AMD):

```
  0  x: DOT4        R0.x, -R0.y,  R1.x      
     y: DOT4        ____,  R0.x,  R1.y      
     z: DOT4        ____, -R0.w,  R1.z      
     w: DOT4        ____,  R0.z,  R1.w
```

Instead you see extra MOVs. However, it isn't looks like valid code (I don't think DOT can take partially-negated arguments. Can't say more without carefully reading instructions manual), so compiler adds extra MOV (which is not necessarily results in extra cycle, by the way - depends on other instructions nearby).

Comment: +1 cycle compared to what? - Not compared - that instruction just takes 1 cycle(in best case, according to AMD shader analyzer). With define working solution there will be no overhead at all.

Comment: And it looks like AMD can do per-component negotiation. If I understand this right z: MOV         R0.z,  R1.z      
         w: MOV         R1.w, -R1.w      
         t: MOV         R1.y, -R1.y That's from HD2900 assembly (from AMD shader analyzer)

Comment: Perhaps, they don't have assembly representation and I haven't red their latest instructions manual. But I'm not getting what you want - to make assign cost 0 cycles? Not going to happen, any operation costs something. 1 is very good already (as in my second example).

Comment: Even swizzling? Without redifinition to other value? Look at my not worked 1st exampled :)

Comment: No, swizzling costs virtually nothing, but it isn't instruction. Assign (mov), however, is an instruction and costs at least one cycle (if not bundled with another compatible instructions - in that case, they will run in parallel, but still consume at least one cycle together).